# The correct term for a collection of homework?

Tags: homework

I'm looking for the correct wording for a collection of homework that will be given to students throughout the duration of a course/class.

So far I came up with Homework Plan. But I'm wondering if this is correct or widely used or not?

For example: My `insert proper term here` for the term consists of 6 assignments.

Comment: I think that anything will do. The students will get the idea. There is a site here on proper English usage, of course. https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "There will be a total of six homework assignments for the term."

Comment: I'd say `portfolio`.

Comment: I agree with the version of @Vladhagen; why introduce a new noun when the plural form serves just fine?

Comment: I don't really understand the close votes. This seems like a reasonable question for someone constructing a syllabus (for a university course) to ask... I also agree with Vladhagen's version by the way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how I would phrase it:

> There will be a total of six homework assignments for the term.

This statement is completely unambiguous. Say it straight. No need to be cute.

Phrases like "My homework portfolio for the term consists of six assignments" and "Homework plan" could potentially be confusing to students. What's a homework portfolio? Do I need to keep it in a special folder? Does it need to be labelled? Are there other assignments besides this portfolio? Why, as a student, would I care what your plans are? You either have homework to assign or you don't.

Answer (score 2):

I advise against using language that can be construed as confusing or clumsy. Just plain English should suffice.

*The entire semester homework will consist of six assignments.*

*The total homework over the course will consist of six assignments.*

*The total homework over the term will comprise six assignments.*

..........

and so on and so forth….

Vladhagen’s version is also crystal clear; it can help avoid clumsy style and ambiguity.

Comment: Probably this post and question should be moved to some other StackExchange section (or even deleted) after Robby Reindeer receives the necessary answer. No disrespect is meant at all.